# Не запускается приложение на Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Возникла проблема с приложением, написанным и тестированным на node.js v4 и node.js v5
Вообщем при запуске командой node app.js вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
    [root@LEX-DATA src]# node app.js
warn: Sails' built-in layout support only works with the `ejs`, `handlebars`, `ractive` view engines.
warn: You're using `jade`.
warn: Ignoring `sails.config.views.layout`...
/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:281
              throw e;
              ^

`include-all` attempted to `require(/opt/projects/harvest/src/api/services/HarvestService.js)`, but an error occurred::
Details:TypeError: Harvest is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/projects/harvest/src/api/services/HarvestService.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:271:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _recursivelyIncludeAll (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:174:11)
    at includeAll (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:292:5)
    at helpBuildDictionary (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-build-dictionary.js:43:15)
    at Function.module.exports.optional (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:67:10)
    at Hook.loadServices (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:424:18)
    at Hook.wrapper [as loadServices] (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at Hook.loadModules (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/services/index.js:68:21)
    at Hook.wrapper [as loadModules] (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at Array.async.auto.modules (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:79:27)
    at /opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:591:38
    at _arrayEach (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
    at Object.async.auto (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:552:9)
    at Hook.load (/opt/projects/harvest/src/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:73:13)
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема кроется в двух файлах: в help-include-all-sync.js в строчке:

```
e.stack = '`include-all` attempted to `require('+filepath+')`, but an error occurred:: \nDetails:' + e.stack;
          throw e;
```

А так же при запуске ругается что Harvest is not a function

```
        `include-all` attempted to `require(/opt/projects/harvest/src/api/services/HarvestService.js)`, but an error occurred::
    Details:TypeError: Harvest is not a function
 at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/projects/harvest/src/api/services/HarvestService.js:2:22)
```

Вот строчка:

```
var Harvest = require('harvest');
var HarvestService = new Harvest(sails.config.harvest);
```

В чем может быть проблема и как приложение то запустить ?

Comment: в package.json есть библиотека harvest?

Comment: да, присутствует

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, у Вас там подключен `jade`, а `Sails` поддерживает `ejs`, `handlebars`, `ractive` из-за этого все и валиться.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко jade отключил, поставил ejs, warn теперь действительно исчезли, но главная проблема все равно видимо в harvest. Как ругался что harvest is not a function так и ругается и не дает запустить приложение.